# fabricjs - moving group by selection only one of the item

Tags: fabricjs

I have added a `fabric.Group` on canvas and I would like to allow moving group by selection only one of the item in the group. Is there a way to customize shape of selection area?

Answer (score 0):

So when you select one object, is it ok that you select the whole group?

Did you try: 
canvas.selection = true;   // doc @ http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

Else you have to design something like this (not complete):

```
canvas.on({
  'object:moving': function(e) {
    var movObj = e.target;
    var arrGroup = getObjects();
    for (var i = 0; i < arrGroup.length; i++) {
       // if(arrGroup[i] != movObj) // maybe at this for preformance
       arrGroup[i].left = calcDiff; // calc the diff
       arrGroup[i].top = calcDiff;
    }
  },

});
```